# using WHERE if criteria meet else using another WHERE

Tags: sql

my example is here:

```
Select T1.*,
       TC.country_name,
       TS.state_name,
       T1.address_type
From mtpd2_virtuemart_order_userinfos T1
     Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_countries TC On TC.virtuemart_country_id = T1.virtuemart_country_id
     Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_states TS On TS.virtuemart_state_id = T1.virtuemart_state_id
Where T1.address_type ='ST' OR T1.address_type = 'BT'
      And T1.virtuemart_order_id /*SELECTED_ID_LIST*/
```

the logic I'm looking for is to use `(WHERE T1.address_type='ST')` if string inside the cell was 'ST' otherwise use `(WHERE T1.address_type='BT')`

[image]

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add the tag(s) for the database you are really using.  And I think you just want `in`:  `WHERE T1.address_type IN ('ST', 'BT')`.

Comment: in the situation of one row contain 'ST' & another 'BT' choose 'ST' row but if there is no ST in the row choose 'BT' row which is the only option.

Comment: i should mention that we have a situation of 'BT' & 'ST' together. it means i want if there was 2 row one contain 'ST' another 'BT' then only choose 'ST' (WHERE T1.address_type='ST') But if we only had one row and it was 'BT' then choose 'BT'

Comment: From the fact that Alim's answer didnt work for you, I'm guessing your problem isn't the contents of the `where` clause. It would help if you posted - your table structure - some sample data for your table and - the corresponding output(s) you're expecting for your sample data.

Comment: sure.  we have 1 table with columns of  (customer_neme)  (adress_type)  (user_id)  another 2 table for country and state name left joined to this main table. now we want in the first place to show rows of table which have 'ST' content in (adress_type) column. then if there wasnt any 'ST', system shows us row contain 'BT', which remain the only options...

Comment: in another sort i want that system at the first place call rows with 'ST' and if there wasn't any 'ST', system should call anything has left. but in a situation that we have 2 row of same customer id like (12454      ST        345) & (13565   BT    345)  system should call or read  'ST' row and amite 'BT' row

Answer (score 0):

Just use parantheses and negate the the ST part in the second clause:

```
Select T1.*,
   TC.country_name,
   TS.state_name,
   T1.address_type
From mtpd2_virtuemart_order_userinfos T1
    Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_countries TC On TC.virtuemart_country_id = T1.virtuemart_country_id
     Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_states TS On TS.virtuemart_state_id =     T1.virtuemart_state_id
Where 
     (T1.address_type ='ST' OR (T1.address_type <>'ST' && T1.address_type = 'BT'))
And T1.virtuemart_order_id /*SELECTED_ID_LIST*/
```

Comment: there is priority with 'ST'. but choosing your code it used 'BT'

Answer (score 0):

Surrounding your OR statement with parenthesis should suffice for what you are looking.

```
WHERE (T1.address_type ='ST' OR T1.address_type = 'BT')
AND T1.virtuemart_order_id
```

Comment: there is no deference.. bring 'BT' in any condition. i want IF 'ST' doesn't exist bring WHERE 'BT'

Answer (score 0):

This can be a way to solve the problem, though I am not sure if this is the most optimum way:
1. Create a table having only address_type='ST' as tableA
2. Create another table having only address_type='BT' and the customer_ids which do not exist in tableA--- say this table be tableB
Append (Concatenate/Union) the two tables

This code may serve the purpose:

```
select * from
    (Select T1.*,
           TC.country_name,
           TS.state_name,
           T1.address_type
    From mtpd2_virtuemart_order_userinfos T1
         Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_countries TC On TC.virtuemart_country_id = T1.virtuemart_country_id
         Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_states TS On TS.virtuemart_state_id = T1.virtuemart_state_id
    Where T1.address_type ='ST'
          And T1.virtuemart_order_id /*SELECTED_ID_LIST*/) as A
    Union

select * from
    (Select T1.*,
           TC.country_name,
           TS.state_name,
           T1.address_type
    From mtpd2_virtuemart_order_userinfos T1
         Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_countries TC On TC.virtuemart_country_id = T1.virtuemart_country_id
         Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_states TS On TS.virtuemart_state_id = T1.virtuemart_state_id
    Where T1.address_type = 'BT'
          And T1.virtuemart_order_id /*SELECTED_ID_LIST*/
          And TS.state_id not in ( select TS.state_name
                                   From mtpd2_virtuemart_order_userinfos T1
                                   Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_countries TC On                         TC.virtuemart_country_id = T1.virtuemart_country_id
         Left Join mtpd2_virtuemart_states TS On TS.virtuemart_state_id = T1.virtuemart_state_id
    Where T1.address_type ='ST'
          And T1.virtuemart_order_id /*SELECTED_ID_LIST*/ ) ) as B
```

Comment: unfortunately creating table is not an option.  i believe there is an easy way in SQL coding to make priority in where syntax... am i wrong?

Comment: @alifath Yes there might be other ways too, but I could think of this. By the way in this case also, you do not need to create separate table, subquery can cater the requirement.

Comment: its an sql query for fastreport 5.3 report designer. you mean the query make dummy or unreal tables temporary?  i used the code and sql edtor says syntax erorr for 'as' and not exist

Comment: @alifath.. yes, you got it rite, the query will create virtual tables. I have done some changes in the code. Please try it now

Comment: invalid select statement unexpected token (as)  at line 9

Comment: @alifath, please try it now

Comment: invalid select statement. unexpected token at line 2 pos 5

Comment: Use Select * from I missed from after Select * in 2 places

Comment: no hope. doesn't show any error but wont open or call state & country table

Comment: Use the logic... I am not sure about the table names